Pass array of objects as params (C# 11)
Edit: I'm stupid :sob: and I didn't actually have all the parameters in the array. Problem nonexistent :D
I'm creating an instance of a class that inherits from a class Entity (Monocle.Entity, if that's any importance) using Activator.CreateInstance. I have a Type variable and an object[] variable that I pass into this. I use the following line of code:
Entity entity = (Entity)Activator.CreateInstance(info.type, parameters);

However, I'm not trying to pass an object array - I want to pass a variable number of parameters.
When I tried to use spreads,
Entity entity = (Entity)Activator.CreateInstance(info.type, ..parameters);

I got the error Cannot implicitly convert type 'object[]' to 'System.Index'. I realized I'm using C# 11, not C# 12, and as I'm making a mod for Celeste, I need to use .NET 7. (If C# 12 can be used with .NET 7, then correct me and I suppose that solves my problem.) So I essentially need to replicate the functionality of spreads in C# 11. I can use a different type than object[] if that makes things easier.
Edit: The error I'm getting when I simply pass the object[] follows:
Crash Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'Celeste.Spring' not found.
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)


What is the signature of the method you are calling? is the argument parameters declared with the params annotation?

A lambda that returns object[] is declared, then its ran and stored in an object[] variable.

If this is the overload you are using, you are supposed to pass an object?[] indeed. What is the issue there?

WIth VS2022, You can use C# 12 syntax with .NET 7 or even .NET Framework 4.8, because compiler supports it. On your .csproj file add <LangVersion>12.0</LangVersion> on PropertyGroup to use C#12 syntax features. Whether the features you used are compilable or working correctly with older target framework, is another story.

It's very useful if you want to use Raw string literal on .Net Framework btw.

...[continuing] But it seems you are using this overload instead. Even for this case, a simple object[] should work.

The problem is that it says that there's no constructor that's just an array of objects when I just pass the array of objects.

After setting the version to 12.0, I still get the error Cannot implicitly convert type 'object[]' to 'System.Index'. Code: Entity entity = (Entity)Activator.CreateInstance(info.type, ..parameters);

   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)



However, I'm not trying to pass an object array - I want to pass a variable number of parameters.

When you do:
Entity entity = (Entity)Activator.CreateInstance(info.type, parameters);

If your variable parameters is an object[], then you are actually passing a list of parameters, not one parameter which is an array.
See here for reference:

When you call a method with a params parameter, you can pass in:

A comma-separated list of arguments of the type of the array elements.
A collection of arguments of the specified type.
No arguments. If you send no arguments, the length of the params list is zero.


That means, passing new object[] {1, 3, 4} as the last parameter is the same as passing 1, 2, 3 as separate parameters.
The catch here is the following:

An array argument can be passed, as long as the array
type matches the parameter type of the method being called.

In your case, as you seem to be using this overload of the Activator.CreateInstance, which is:
public static object? CreateInstance (Type type, params object?[]? args);

Just make sure you pass a variable or expression of type object?[] or object[], and you should be good.

I should be good, but I'm getting this error:
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)

I am passing an object[].
Entity entity = (Entity)Activator.CreateInstance(info.type, parameters);```

This indicates that your issue may not lie on the parameters passing, but on something else.
